# R heatmap using interpolation

Tags: r, interpolation, heatmap

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508059/simple-r-3d-interpolation-surface-plot) explains how to create a matrix from x/y/z coordinates using the akima package but I'd rather not use a new package. After all, you can do the same thing in one command in gnuplot: [gnuplot interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282302/reduce-distance-between-points-in-splot).

The image plot using a matrix of data points in the above gnuplot thread can be achieved in R with a call to the image() command.

What about a surface plot, how can we interpolate the x/y/z points to generate a 2d heatmap?

Comment: What do you mean by *the standard R commands?* Everything in `base`? or what is loaded when you open R? Are you happy enough to use the core packages that are (usually) included with R?

Comment: The approach in the linked thread is what is described for 2d interpolation in the MASS book. Sounds pretty standard to me...

Comment: @mnel Alright, alright... I just wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier way to plot an interpolated matrix using the core packages. No reason to get tense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you don't like `akima::interp`, maybe `stats::loess` is to your taste?

```
topo.loess <- loess (z ~ x * y, topo, degree = 2, span = 0.2)
x <- seq (min (topo$x), max (topo$x), .05)
y <- seq (min (topo$y), max (topo$y), .05)
interpolated <- predict (topo.loess, expand.grid (x = x, y = y))
image (x= x, y= y, z = interpolated, asp = 1)
points (topo)
```

(also along the lines of MASS)

[image: smoothed interpolation]

Otherwise: why not use gnuplot? Though it may be considered a different piece of software as well...

Comment: I just asked this because I've found weird we can plot a matrix image in one command, but we have to use a special package to run a simple interpolation. Very enough, thanks.

Comment: @RobertKubrick: you may notice that this interpolation is not that simple: it is not restricted to data that is already on an even grid, and `loess` is quite a sophisticated smoothing interpolation. Besides, I think it reflects R's emphasis on statistics together with the fact that there is not just "simple" interpolation but different interpolating models. I really recommend Ch. 15 of the MASS book.